# How to prioritize DNS address with multiple DHCP scopes

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

At my company our DHCP server is configured with multiple scopes.

Two of them is responsible for giving IP addresses to notebooks.
Scope A gives IP address for LAN connection. Uses subnet 255.255.0.0
Scope B gives IP address for Wireless connection. Uses subnet 255.255.240.0

Whenever a notebook connects on LAN, Scope A gives it an IP address and it gets registered in the DNS server.
When WiFi is turned on on the notebook, Scope B will be prioritized and changes the DNS name to the wireless address.
When I disable and re enable the LAN interface, it will register the LAN address again.

Is it possible to always priorize LAN DNS over wireless, so the DNS name will always point to the LAN ip address when possible (even when both LAN and wireless are connected) and only change to Wireless address when LAN is not present?

If you need additional information, ask in a comment and I will update my question.

**Update:**

I have found a workaround.
In the VLAN scope properties DNS tab I have set the option `Dynamically update DNS A and PTR recors only if requested by the DHCP clients`
Also another setting was needed on the client side:
Inside LAN interface IPv4 properties - Advanced - DNS tab, after checking the `Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration`, it started working just how we wanted to.

Now there are two options.
A. We find a way to roll out this setting to all of our clients.
B. We find a way to push this setting from DHCP server side.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Just add the LAN DNS to your WiFi DHCP scope, then clients will always have that DNS present.

Comment: @Bungicasse - But if LAN is not present, the WiFi scope should register instead

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the WiFi scope can be set to broadcast the DNS address of the LAN scope as primary DNS AND the WiFi scope DNS as secondary, then if you are not connected to LAN it will simply use the WiFi scope DNS instead.

Comment: @Bungicasse - Could you write this as an answer with some step by step explanation on how is this done?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to a windows-server since I am at work.. Therefore I think it's best to leave the question unanswered for now and see if anyone else has any other ideas.

Comment: This sounds like a GPO with a WMI (just wireless interfaces) filter to me. But this filter will be interesting to build ...